# Adding an extra tab in the ICS Launcher

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, launcher

I'm on Android 4.0.4. When I open my launcher, I see two tabs — Apps and Widgets. I'd like to add a third tab for Games. Is this possible?

Since I have quite a few games, I'd like to keep them separate and a new tab would be great. If there's an app that'd be awesome.

Any other suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the only way to do this would be to use a custom launcher. I've found three options that have this capability.

[Nova Launcher Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwMiwiY29tLnRlc2xhY29pbHN3LmxhdW5jaGVyLnByaW1lIl0.) ($4.00)

[Apex Launcher Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher.pro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmRkb2VzLmxhdW5jaGVyLnBybyJd) ($3.99)

[Holo Launcher Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobint.hololauncherplus&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwMiwiY29tLm1vYmludC5ob2xvbGF1bmNoZXJwbHVzIl0.) ($3.99)

There is also a free [Holo Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobint.hololauncher&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwMiwiY29tLm1vYmludC5ob2xvbGF1bmNoZXIiXQ..), but I don't think it has the customizable tabs.

Comment: Nova Launcher Prime looks great. I'll give that a shot. Cheers.